# CSS z-index usage?

Tags: html, css, web

I'm doing CSS, but I have no idea how to use the z-index function. Here is what I have so far:

```css
body {
    background-image: url("design1.jpg"), url("northpole2.jpg"), url("chessbackground.jpg"), url("clipart3102234.png"), url("grassblock.jpg"), url("photoborder.jpg"), url("website\ background\ color.jpg");
    z-index: 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-size: 700px 290px, 700px 290px, 250px 250px, 200px 200px, 250px 250px,850px 300px, 200px 200px;
    background-position-x: 0%, 100%, 0%, 98%, 100%, 50%, 50%;
    background-position-y: 0%, 0%, 24%, 24%, 24%, 24%, 24%;
    background-color: rgb(170, 154, 154);
}
```

I'm doing this so I can layer some of the images inside of the background. Help with this would be greatly appreciated. Edit: I have made some changes to the code but it still won't work:

```css
body {
    background-image: url("design1.jpg"), url("northpole2.jpg"), url("chessbackground.jpg"), url("clipart3102234.png"), url("grassblock.jpg"), url("photoborder.jpg"), url("website\ background\ color.jpg");
    z-index: 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-size: 700px 290px, 700px 290px, 250px 250px, 200px 200px, 250px 250px,850px 300px, 10px 10px;
    background-position-x: 0%, 100%, 0%, 98%, 100%, 50%, 50%;
    background-position-y: 0%, 0%, 24%, 24%, 24%, 24%, 24%;
    background-color: rgb(170, 154, 154);
}
```

Edit: I have found the solution for this issue, it is to declare the one you want top most as the first closest to the background-image function like this:

```css
body {
    background-image: url("paperbackground.jpg"), url("design1.jpg"), url("northpole2.jpg"), url("chessbackground.jpg"), url("clipart3102234.png"), url("grassblock.jpg"), url("photoborder.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-size: 650px 200px, 700px 290px, 700px 290px, 250px 250px, 200px 200px, 250px 250px, 835px 365px;
    background-position-x: 50%, 0%, 100%, 0%, 98%, 100%, 50%, 50%;
    background-position-y: 30%, 0%, 0%, 24%, 24%, 24%, 24%, 24%;
    background-color: rgb(170, 154, 154);
}
```

Comment: While you can't give a z-index to individual background images you can write them in the order in which you want them shown 'z-wise'. Unlike elements, the first image is higher than the second and so on. So reorder your image list.

Comment: thanks man really helped with this, but how would i implement this into my current code?

Answer (score -1):

There is no z-index for background images as z-index is element based.
For more info :-
[CSS: Z-index of multiple backgrounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915542/css-z-index-of-multiple-backgrounds)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may answer the question, rather than have an answer that points to another Stack Overflow answer - there is a system to flag duplicates. Once you have more site rep you will be able to do this. Until then, try not to leave link only answers - provide code examples to demonstrate, or write the relevant information in the answer itself.

Answer (score -1):

You cant use z-index like this..Z-index helps to move elements or layers from front to back back to front or anyhow order you want.and also i think it's not possible to use z-index for background.how ever please try with different values.don't use same values..bigger z-index value means it comes front!